# Using a model for multiple purposes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC using Entity Framework and I'm trying to create a simple login system. At the moment I have `UserProfile` model that I wish to model a login form off of.

**UserProfile.cs**

```
namespace MyProject.Areas.Admin.Models
{
    public class UserProfile {

        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }

    }
}
```

As my login form will only require a username and password, is it correct for me to create a separate model (for instance, a `LoginModel` with just those properties, or should I contine to use the `UserProfile` model?

It feels better for me to create a separate model to model the login submission, but then I run into the issues such as making them reference the same table?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have only one `Model` (Domain model), but different `ViewModel` class.

The `ViewModel` will only have the properties (from the Model) needed for a certain `View` /`Action`.

To manage mapping between `Model` and `ViewModel`(s), you should look at Mapping solutions (like AutoMapper, ValueInjecter...)

Comment: I see! That certainly makes a lot more sense. So just to clarify; create a `LoginViewModel` and map the `Username` and `Password` properties from the `UserProfile` the view model?

Comment: @BigJoe Well, yes : UserProfile is the Model, and LoginViewModel is the ViewModel. When you wanna load data to display them in a view, you map from Model to ViewModel. If you need to update datas coming from a View, you map ViewModel to Model.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you should distinguish view model and domain model. Interestin discussion was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680571/mapping-domain-models-to-view-models).